# How to connect in spring boot to PGbouncer?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

I'm tring to connect my spring boot app to PGbouncer connection pool on digital ocean cloud. But I get the error "prepared statement "S_1" already exists". As I understand the issue is Hikari connection pool. Should I turn it off? If yes how to do it? Or maybe exists some other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Add the parameter 'prepareThreshold=0' to connection string fixed problem.